# Case statement for multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 questions.

(1) I have columns `colA, colB, ColC, colD`. I need to change the values in colC.
Based on following condition

If colB =1 then colC = 'Tom1' else if
 the first 3 characters of colD = 'Jef' then  colC = 'Tom2'
Else  Null.

(2) how do I add a default value '12:00 pm' to an integer column ?

Please help me I am needing here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this mysql or SQL Server? You have tagged both.

Comment: `CASE WHEN colB = 1 AND colC = 'Tom1' THEN '' WHEN LEFT(colID,3) = 'Jef' AND colC = 'Tom2' THEN '' ELSE NULL END`

Comment: ColC doesn't have a value called 'Tom1' or 'Tom2'. I need to get it done with case statement @Lamak

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that your desired logic is complete. Such as what do you actually want the value to be retain current colA value?  and you are writing colb = 1 then colC = 'Tom1'... I will assume then is supposed to be and.

```
CASE
   WHEN colB = 1 and colC = 'Tom1' THEN ????
   WHEN LEFT(colD) = 'Jef' AND colC = 'Tom2' THEN ????
   ELSE NULL
END
```

If you just want to retain the ColA Value then you can actually combine yoru case statements with an OR

```
CASE
   WHEN (colB = 1 and colC = 'Tom1')
        OR (LEFT(colD) = 'Jef' AND colC = 'Tom2') THEN colA
   ELSE NULL
END
```

Comment: question looks the same

Comment: How do I add a default value of '12:00 pm' to a integer column??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you fully have the values of colB and colD at the time you are producing colC, you could use something like:

```
select
    colA
    ,colB
    ,case
        when colB = 1 then 'Tom1'
        when left(colD,3) = 'Jef' then 'Tom2'
        else null
    end as colC
    ,colD
```

If colB and colD are also calculated columns and you don't want to repeat the calculations, you could do those in a subquery and calculate colC in an outer query.

```
select
    t1.colA
    ,t1.colB
    ,case
        when t1.colB = 1 then 'Tom1'
        when left(t1.colD,3) = 'Jef' then 'Tom2'
        else null
    end as colC
    ,t1.colD
from
(
    select
        colA
        ,case when someCondition then 1 else 2 end as colB
        ,(select top 1 name from someTable) as colD
    from
        ...   -- whatever your source tables are
) t1
```